# Как выдать участникам полные права доступа к приватному репозиторию?

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий, с ещё двумя участниками(collaborators), как выдать им полные права доступа, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в настройках репы, там же, где выдаются вообще все права участникам

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываешь репозиторий
2. `Settings`
3. `Collaborators`
4. `Add people`

Comment: Это я добавляю как соавторов, но есть ещё же какие-то настройки, чтобы сделать соавторами администраторами репозитория, например(по типу transfer?)